# Multiple charts inside a scrollview automatic scroll up

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm currently using AChartEngine library and i've got 3 charts inside a scrollview. This is my layout file:

```
     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewChartLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/black" >

     <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="15dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/temperatureChartLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="30dp" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/humidityChartLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="30dp" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/lightChartLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

And in the renderer i use:

```
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

The charts draws correclty but when i scroll down with scrollbar the view automatically scroll up after 0.5secs! What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself: i was redrawing all view on new data (and my data arrives continuously). Only need to use mChartView.repaint(); to redraw chart.

Comment: @Alvins My charts in scroll view is not showing without  android:fillViewport="true". Do you have any ideas?